# Concurrency violation while trying to update database (Only on specific table)

Tags: c#, mysql

This issue is driving me crazy.

I am trying to update a dataset with a MySQL dataAdapter. This method works on other tables in my database, its just happening with this table. Here is an example of the code:

```
    String query = "select * from accounts";
    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
    connection.Open();
    MySqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, (MySqlConnection)connection);
    MySqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new MySqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);
    dataAdapter.FillSchema(dataSet, SchemaType.Source);
    commandBuilder.RefreshSchema();
    dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);

    dataSet.Tables[0].Rows[0]["balance"] = 1M;
    dataAdapter.Update(dataSet);
```

Once it tries to update it throws the exception. And keep in mind this is a simplified example of my code, but it gets the same result.

I've researched the error and all I could find is:
1) If this data has changed by another user since the Fill
2) If the row doesn't exist.

But there is no possible way the data is being changed by another user because this happens on my development machine. And the row obviously exists since it doesn't throw an exception at Rows[0].

And as I said this only happens on this one table. The table has an int as the primary key and the column I'm trying to update is a Decimal so I have no clue what the problem is.

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: Can't see anything in the code. Not your issue I think, but I should point out when it says row doesn't exist. It means in the table, ie it thinks the update statement corresponds to a non existent row. Have you made sure nothing's gone wrong with your key in the table. The other reason you'd get this is if the row could not be uniquely identified. ie select * from Table Where ID =1 returned anything other than 1 row. Unlikely, but I've seen it happen, for one reason or another

Comment: Not sure if this will help, but I had a similar problem, years ago, with a different DB. IIRC it was some sort of mapping issue, where a date was stored as a number or similar. When the row got sent back to the DB, the DB saw that the values weren't the same and complained that the data had been changed (even though it wasn't). Maybe you can check out the DataSet's definition and compare to the DB? Not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this was posted a while ago but I just found a solution to my issue:

It seems the problem was with the table structure or something like that. I did a mysqldump on the table, then just imported the dump (which essentially builds the table from scratch). After I did that everything works like a charm.

Hopefully I can help someone else having this strange issue.